# Facts can not be deleted automatically when I use sliding window

Tags: java, drools

The `Drools` version is 6.2.0, and **I'am using the Stream Mode**.

I used @timestamp to tell engine to use the timestamp from the event's attribute.

The question is the number of Facts in WorkingMemory is larger and larger, and facts not retract even the fact is expired(10s).

I tryed to use Pseudo Clock, but it also take No effect.

this is my drl:

```
package test.drools

import test.drools.LogEntry;

declare LogEntry
    @role(event)
    @timestamp(callDateTime)
end

rule "sliding-window-test"
    when
        $msgA: LogEntry($sip: sourceIP)
        Number(intValue > 2) from accumulate (
            $msgB: LogEntry(sourceIP == $sip, this after $msgA) over     window:time(10s); count($msgB))
    then
        System.out.println("rule sliding-window-test action actived!!");
        retract($msgA)
end
```

this my code:

```
    public class LogEntry {
    private String logcontent = null;
    private String[] logFieldStrArray = null;

    private String sourceIP = null;
    private long callDateTime;

    public LogEntry(String content) {
        this.logcontent = content;
        if (logFieldStrArray == null) {
            logFieldStrArray = logcontent.split("\\,");
        }

        sourceIP = logFieldStrArray[6];

        **callDateTime = System.nanoTime();**
    }

    public long getcallDateTime() {
        return callDateTime;
    }

    public String getsourceIP() {
        return sourceIP;
    }
}
```

The session configuration is correct, here just show how to call clock advanceTime.
use Pseudo Clock, advanceTime.

```
    public class DroolsSession {
    private long beginTime = 0, curTime = 0;

    private statfulKsession;

    private Object syncobject;

    public void InsertAndFireAll(Object obj) {
        synchronized(syncobject) {
            if (beginTime == 0) {
                beginTime = ((LogEntry)obj).getcallDateTime();
            } else {
                curTime = ((LogEntry)obj).getcallDateTime();
                long l = advanceTime(curTime - beginTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                beginTime = curTime;
            }
            statfulKsession.insert(obj);
            statfulKsession.fireAllRules();
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I use the `System.nanoTime()`, does `Drools` support `nanoTime`?

I'm looking forward to your answer.It is my pleasure.

Comment: I know @expires() for LogEntry events would work.  But I don't know what a "safe" time would be since there will be more rules, and these new rules maybe use LogEntry, so the Drools engine should take responsibility for managing the lifecycle of facts in working memory.

Answer (score 0):

What the condition of rule "sliding-window-test" says is: 
If there is a LogEntry event A (no matter what, no matter how old) and
if there are more that two LogEntry events later than A and with the same sourceIP that have arrived in the last 10 seconds: then retract A.

This does not permit to retract LogEntry events automatically, because it is
always possible for the second condition to be fulfilled at some later time.